# String with negative float to float?

Tags: c#

Here is basically the code I have :

```
string text = "-0.05537987";

float value = Single.Parse(text);
```

When I try and parse a negative number like I did here I get "Input string was not in the correct format."

Comment: It worked for me. Using .NET 4.0 Client on Windows 7. Maybe the problem is elsewhere in your code?

Comment: The problem was elsewhere sorry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your parsing should work, I believe your current culture has a different character for decimal separator. Use [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)

```
float value = Single.Parse(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Or he could change his thread culture to appropriate culture... Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("his-string-format-culture");

Comment: @user3740638, are you sure the value you have in text is `"-0.05537987"`  ? it should work.

Comment: Ummmmmmmm im an idiot. In my actual code i was splitting the string using dashes and the dash for the negative split the string and messed everything up. Sorry and Thanks for the quick responses.

Answer (score 4):

Your code works fine for me - https://dotnetfiddle.net/JfPfss

Use InvariantCulture and see if that is the issue:

```
float value = Single.Parse(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

```
string text = "-0.05537987";
float value = Single.Parse(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
MessageBox.Show("your value = "+value);
```